# How to properly handle this follow up situation

Tags: interviewing, job-search, hiring-process, meetings, phone

I think that this is a common thing that everyone runs into. I am currently looking for a new job. I received a call on Thursday and the HR person was wondering if I might be available on Sunday for an informal meeting with the hiring manager. I was available for an informal meeting. She then said that she would call back on Saturday for basically a phone interview for the position.

On Saturday, I received the phone call and we proceeded with the interview. I think that it went ok; there were a few technical questions that I wasn't sure of the answer. Once done, she said that she would pass my contact information over to the hiring manager so that we could talk directly to setup a phone interview (he was headed to another city and passing through my city along the way, hence the informal meeting).

Sunday came and I waited and waited and never received any kind of phone call. Today (Monday) I called the HR person from the number that she called me and left a message following up with her. I informed her that I did not receive a phone call from the hiring manager and I was wondering if I was still being considered for the position. I also left my number so that I can be called back (She probably has the number on file since it is on my resume).

It is almost closing time and I have not received any further communication from the hiring manager or the HR person.

What should I do? Should I wait until I get some communication or should I do some more follow up? Have I been dropped from the position or should I wait until I get the email saying that we will not be considering you for the position?

(As a side note, this is my first full-time professional job. I had some internship positions before but they responded quite quickly on these so I am not used to these long delays).

Edit:

This is not the same as the suggested posting mainly because there was no scheduled time for the informal meeting and it is an informal meeting and not an interview (although, I wonder if there is really any difference between the two) The hiring manager was suppose to call me to setup an informal meeting to which he/she did not call at all. There was not time at which he/she would contact me. That was left up to the hiring manager. That is also assuming that the HR person actually forwarded my contact information to the hiring manager and the hiring manager received it.

Comment: Usually you should get an email when there was an interview and was not done. You should have called them on Sunday when you expected the call. In any case you did the follow up. You can also drop an email and just let it go. These are signs of poor planning so you need to take that into account. By the way what kind of company is it that they are interviewing during weekends?

Comment: It is a software company. I would divulge the name but it would be really awkward if one of their employees (or themselves) ran across this question. I do not have an email address that I can send email to them. There was no set time for the informal meeting or when the hiring manager would call me. The only item that I have for contacting them is the HR person's number. And even then, I do not know if it is their personal number or office number. I guess I should just wait it out?

Comment: So should I consider an informal meeting = interview?

Comment: If you have no email you have nothing to lose by making one more attempt to ask what happened with the scheduled meeting. But do not stop your search for them. So far they raised many flags such as poor planning and organization, interview during the weekend which hints to strange work hours and meetings during weekends wasting your time as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Continue with your search**

Either they are not really interested in hiring you, or they are just been slow.

In any case, it is in your uttermost interest to talk with multiple companies. That way, you will have more options to decide, more leverage to negotiate, and timing will also be in your side.

Do **not** wait for a company that misses an interview with you. Let them chase you instead ;)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Good news though, this company is 1 of like 70 others that I applied to. It is just, this is the first time something like this happened to me and I wasn't sure how I should handle it because it might happen again with another company!

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here:

1. "I would like to send them an email but I was not given any email address. "  <-- This isn't helping your situation any if you can't call, speak to the receptionist or customer service, and ASK for an e-mail address.  Businesses are looking for problem solvers... and I'll leave it at that.
2. If the company's operating hours are normally Monday to Friday, it's a little shady sounding that interviewing activity got pushed to the weekend.  This, in itself, may be a red-flag.
3. No call from the hiring manager, no follow up at all from HR.  It seems that you, or at least your time, are expendable!!!  This is a precedent, and it means you can't really expect better treatment if you're hired.

My suggestion: **move on**.  If you get a call back, great.  Don't leave any more messages, because at this point it starts to reek of desperation on your part (meaning they'll offer you the lowest rate they can, if you're offered anything).

I'd also recommend some training or reading on how to be a little more assertive.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, moving forward, I think that I am going to always ask for an email address and ask when I should be expecting the call.